# How to sanitize URL-escaped String in Java?

Tags: java, owasp, html-sanitizing

I am using org.owasp.html.PolicyFactory class to build my policy. It sanitizes text like

```
<script>alert(...);</script>
```

but does nothing with text like

```
%3cscript%3ealert(...)%3c/script%3e
```

One solution is to decode text first:

```
URLDecoder.decode(oldValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

but I don't know is it the right way to do it, what bugs can appear, in what cases the exceptions will be thrown, etc.
Does OWASP library supports such feature?

Comment: Beware - there is no way to sanitize arbitrary text for all possible use cases. If a library supports n iterations of decoding, an attacker only needs to add another level of encoding.

Comment: The general advice is to never sanitize, but only escape/encode for the specific output context.

Comment: Found this OWASP Java Encoder reference which might be useful https://owasp.org/www-project-java-encoder/